# Satoshi Bitcoin account profile

Tags: account-control

i tried to withdraw from my Satoshi mining account but, A noticed that the Bitcoin is prohibited in my country or region (Nigeria)?

Comment: Bitcoin mining requires expensive specialised equipment, anything that suggests you can mine with a PC or a phone is a scam.

Comment: I disagree with you. Everything _can_ actually perform multiple SHA256d(). It will certainly not be productive but don't say that anything suggests you can mine with a PC or a smartphone is a _scam_...

Comment: @Loopite: You will pay magnitudes more in electricity than what you earn, and your devices will wear from the constant computations. RedGrittyBrick is right to categorize that sort of narrative as a red flag for a scam.

Comment: Hi Thomas, we don’t have any special insight into some company’s inner workings. If you think there is a legitimate customer support issue here, you need to take it up with them, but please also consider whether this might not be a legitimate business at all, since mining requires special hardware to be profitable and doesn’t just produce significant revenue for end users.